# how to write output in excel in different columns using python?

Tags: python

I have 10 csv as input having some columns. I have calculated four output for each csv like mean, avg, median ,mode. I want to store this output in excel in a sheet for all 10 csv.

```
wb=Workbook()

# add_sheet is used to create sheet.
sheet1=wb.add_sheet('DM_Assignment')

sheet1.write(1,0,'1')
sheet1.write(2,0,'2')
sheet1.write(3,0,'3')
sheet1.write(4,0,'4')
sheet1.write(0,0,'CSVs')
sheet1.write(0,1,'Mean')
sheet1.write(0,2,'Median')
sheet1.write(0,3,'Mode')
sheet1.write(0,4,'Average')

wb.save('check.xls')
```

Comment: i want output as 

CSV Mean Mode Median Average
1        10       9         5            8
2         9         8        4             7
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: Read about the paramter of [Worksheet.write](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=worksheet%20write#xlwt.Worksheet.Worksheet.write)